# Facing issue mocking the IServiceProvider extensions method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq

I am aware this question might be repeated but I am facing an issue where I cant mock the non-static method as it is the static method that is calling the non-static method.

My controller logic calls the static `ServiceProviderServiceExtensions` method `GetServices<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)` which in turn seems to call the non-static method `provider.GetService(serviceType)`.

Basically, I have dependency injection where one interface has two implementations as

```
services.AddSingleton<IProvider, CustomProvider1>();
services.AddSingleton<IProvider, CustomProvider2>();
```

Now, I have 2 controllers which directly take the dependency on this provider as:

```
 public Controller1(IProvider provider)
 public Controller2(IProvider provider)
```

In my controller, I resolve dependencies as

```
Controller1.cs

provider = serviceProvider.GetServices<IProvider>()
                .FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.GetType() == typeof(CustomeProvider1));
            and

Controller2.cs
provider = serviceProvider.GetServices<IProvider>()
                .FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.GetType() == typeof(CustomeProvider1));
```

Now, when I try to mock my unit tests as belows:

```
 serviceProviderMock
                .Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(CustomeProvider2)))
                .Returns(a);
```

I get an error No service for type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`[IProvider]`has been registered.
and I cant directly mock the`GetServicesmethod` as it is static.

Any clue how can I get my tests mocked?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My controller logic calls the static ServiceProviderServiceExtensions method GetServices(this IServiceProvider provider)

This is where things will start to go wrong. Calling `GetServices<T>` from within your controller is an application of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). All troubles you have are originating from this misuse.

Instead, you should:

1. Solely use constructor injection
2. Never inject `IServiceProvider` of another abstraction that represents the container in a constructor of any class outside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)

So this means you should have a constructor as follows:

```
public Controller1(IProvider provider)
```

Your `IProvider` is ambiguous, but let's assume for a moment that this is okay. What's not okay, however, is to let application code deal with this ambiguity. Instead, you should solely handle this ambiguity inside your Composition Root, which can be done as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton<CustomProvider1>();
services.AddTransient<Controller1>(c => new Controller1(
    c.GetRequiredService<CustomProvider1>()));

services.AddSingleton<CustomProvider2>();
services.AddTransient<Controller2>(c => new Controller2(
    c.GetRequiredService<CustomProvider2>()));
```

Do note that, by default, ASP.NET Core MVC does not resolve controllers from the DI Container (which is a really, really weird default). So to force MVC to use the DI Container to resolve controllers, and thereby using the above registrations, you will have to add the following code:

```
services.AddMvc()
   .AddControllersAsServices();
```

The above registration only works well in case those controllers only have one dependency, because this method effectively disables auto-wiring. In case the class has more dependencies, a more maintainable construct would be the following:

```
services.AddTransient<Controller1>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Controller1>(
        c,
        c.GetRequiredService<CustomProvider1>()));

services.AddTransient<Controller2>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Controller2>(
        c,
        c.GetRequiredService<CustomProvider1>()));
```

This makes use of .NET Core's `ActivatorUtilities` class, which allows a class to get auto-wired, while passing in certain dependencies.

Do note that `ActivatorUtilities` comes with certain downsides, such as the inability to detect cyclic dependencies. Instead, a stack overflow exception will be thrown (yuck).

But... as I noted previously, your `IProvider` abstraction is ambiguous, because there are two implementations and consumers require a different implementation. Although this isn't a bad thing per se, you should always verify whether or not you are not violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) by doing so.

You can check to see whether you violate the LSP by swapping the two implementations around. So ask yourself: what happens to `Controller1` when it gets injected with a `CustomProvider2` and what will happen to `Controller2` when it gets injected with a `CustomProvider1`. If the answer is that they will stop working, this means that you are violating the LSP and this a design problem.

If the controller breaks, it means that both implementations behave very differently while consumers should be able to assume all implementations behave according to their abstraction. Violating the LSP means adding complexity.

When you determined you *are* violating the LSP in this case, the solution is to give each implementation its own abstraction:

```
interface IProvider1 { }
interface IProvider2 { }
```

Whether or not those two interface have an identical signature is irrelevant, because the LSP violation signals that both interfaces are actually very different in behavior, because swapping out implementations breaks their clients.

Note, however, that even if the direct consumer keeps working, it could still mean that the application starts to behave incorrectly when the implementations are swapped. This doesn't mean you are violating the SRP. For instance, when provider1 logs to disk and provider2 logs to database, the expected behavior is that a call to controller1 will cause a log on disk to be appended. Having it the other way around is therefore not what you want to achieve, but that is something you wish to configure in your Composition Root. That is not an indication of a LSP violation; in that case the contract still behaves as consumers expect it to.

If swapping implementations has no notable effect on their consumers, you are not violating LSP and it means the given registrations are the way to go. Or you can simplify things by starting to us a 'real' DI Container ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Steven. When I tried implementing the services.AddTransient<Controller1>(c =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Controller1>(
        c,
        c.GetRequiredService<CustomProvider1>())); 
I get an error as there are now 2 parametered constructors for my controllers. 
Error is: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type. 
Can we achieve this in one constructor itself that seem to take all required params.

Comment: That' [another anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Your components should have only one constructor.

Comment: ALright, I tried to merge 2 constructors into 1 big contructor. 
Now my Controllers contrucotr takes CustomeProvider1 as a parameter but it is unable to resolve this back to IProvider which makes sense. 
So, I am not sure how directly adding the implementation class references in the constructor is going to solve this problem :(

Comment: If you have "1 big constructor", please make sure your class doesn't have too many dependencies (the [constructor over-injection code smell](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/)). If your class has many dependencies, it is an indication that the class is getting too complex and is violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clear that you will have to register both providers by their concrete types, as in: `services.AddSingleton<CustomProvider1>();`. Without such registration, the provider can't be resolved by its concrete type.